# The waving hand "New contributor" symbol

Tags: discussion, new-users

I have found that labeling the new contributors with the waving hand symbol has a psychological effect that really helps to improve the attitude towards new user accounts. Has it helped any others to count to ten and say something nice despite the understandable frustration?

Answer (score 8):

Not particularly.  I think I pick the same close reasons regardless.  Mostly I find it patronising: "remember to be nice to the other children!".